# How to map table-per-type association?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I've got a SQLite database that was built by `nHibernate` 3 "*code first*"; that's, the model was written first and mapping was done aferward with `Fluent nHibernate`. The database has to be integrated into an application that uses **Entity Framework 6.1.3**. I can't modify the database structure (no `ALTER TABLE`).

**How do I configure the mapping?**

The tables are created like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [Person] (
  [Id] bigint NOT NULL
, [FirstName] text NULL
, [LastName] text NULL
, CONSTRAINT [sqlite_master_PK_Person] PRIMARY KEY ([Id])
);

CREATE TABLE [Patient] (
  [Person_id] bigint NOT NULL
  [Nickname] text NULL
, CONSTRAINT [sqlite_autoindex_Patient_1] PRIMARY KEY ([Person_id])
);
```

The class hierarchy I want to have is:

```
public class Person
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
public class Patient : Person
{
    public string NickName { get; set; }
}
```

All my attempt to map failed because, the mapping (at least by default) is done on the primary key of each table and they have to have the same name. In my case, the id is `ìd` in the table `Person` and `Person_id` in the table `Patient`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the modifications I have done to the map hierarchy:

```
public partial class Person
{
    [Key]
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
public partial class Patient : Person
{
    [Key, Column("Person_id")]
    public new long Id 
    {
        get { return base.Id; }
        set { base.Id = value; }
    }
    public string NickName { get; set; }
}
```